# Conditionally styling SVGs on click events not working on the actual click

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to conditionally change the fill of two svg icons on click events by adding a styling class.

I've managed to get the conditional to add classes on click set up as well as gotten the styling of the svgs set up. However, I can't get the style to change on click. I'm using the react-inlinesvg package to get my svg icons in as inline elements.

```js
class NavBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false
    };
  }

  //changes state for conditional to work
  showDropdown() {
    const { show } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      show: !show
    });
  }

  render() {
    const styles = require('./styles.scss');
    const { show } = this.state;
    const hamburger = require('./hamburger.svg');
    //checks if icon was clicked
    const iconClicked = show ? styles.iconClicked : null

    return (
      <div>
        //click event
        <button type="button" className={styles.hamburger} onClick={() => this.showDropdown()}>
           {/*conditionally adds class to change icon color*/}
           <SVG className={iconClicked} src={hamburger} alt="hamburger" />
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(NavBar);
```

in ./styles.scss :

```css
.iconClicked path{
  fill: blue  !important;
}
```

./hamburger.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="339" height="290" viewBox="0 0 339 290">
  <title>hamburger</title>
  <style>
      path {
        fill:purple;
      }
  </style>
  <path d="M267,406H424a10,10,0,0,1,10,10v0.137a10,10,0,0,1-10,10H267a10,10,0,0,1-10-10V416A10,10,0,0,1,267,406Zm0,73.591H424a10,10,0,0,1,10,10v0.137a10,10,0,0,1-10,10H267a10,10,0,0,1-10-10v-0.137A10,10,0,0,1,267,479.591Zm0,71.272H424a10,10,0,0,1,10,10V561a10,10,0,0,1-10,10H267a10,10,0,0,1-10-10v-0.137A10,10,0,0,1,267,550.863Z" transform="translate(-176 -343)"/>
</svg>
```

The icon changed color when I click to go back a page and return, but not on the actual click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class should be defined in the SVG's wrapper i.e. the button in this case for your example.

```
 <button type="button" className={`${styles.hamburger} ${show ? styles.iconClicked : null}`} onClick={() => this.showDropdown()}>
     <SVG src={hamburger} alt="hamburger" />
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you forgot to do binding for the method. Your state will not be changed when click event is triggered.

```
    class NavBar extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          show: false
        };
        // Added binding here
        this.showDropdown = this.showDropdown.bind(this);
      }
    }
```